# NodeJs MongoDB how to make a complex GET request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm writing a node js method which I want to find fields which the `imei.name` parameters is passed in link and the test field is empty that's the method which I tried to use:

```
 router.get('/gettdata/', (req, res, next) => {
    
        let aa=req.query.imei;
        console.log(aa);
        Post.findOne( {imei:{"imei.name":req.body},
      test:{$exists:false}
      }
    
    
        )
          .then((posts) => {
            res.json(posts);
            console.log(posts);
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
      });
```

it returns an empty field despite it exists when I use only

```
Post.findOne( {"imei.name":req.body})
```

it works and when I use only

```
Post.findOne( 
  test:{$exists:false}
 )
```

it works but the problem is using them two in one time

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eb7f90fb88d8d4d94184333"),
        "imei" : {
                "name" : "bokhhjbr",
                "modele" : "5486"
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eb7fb9cb88d8d4d94184334"),
        "imei" : {
                "name" : "865566048694354",
                "modele" : "CPH1803"
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eba73395fd8dd073065efdf"),
        "imei" : {
                "name" : "bok55555555555hjbr",
                "modele" : "5486"
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-05-12T09:58:17.203Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-05-12T09:58:17.203Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed0f93c0c93ec1c785358ab"),
        "imei" : {
                "name" : "865566048694354"
        },
        "test" : {
                "tactileState" : "1",
                "pixelState" : "1",
                "greyState" : "1"
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the `GET` method, the value of `req.body` will be `{}` object.

That's why `Post.findOne( {"imei.name":req.body})` returns null

You either pass the parameter as either request params of query params. If you are passing it as request params then you GET call would be like

```
http://localhost:3000/post/gettdata?name=865566048694354
```

Now you can access the name in your method like

```js
router.get("/gettdata", (req, res) => {
  let name = req.query.name;
  Post.findOne({'imei.name': name, test: { $exists: false } })
    .then((posts) => {
      res.json(posts);
      console.log(posts);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Error" })
  });
});
```

Also, there was an issue in the syntax for querying nested object, should specify the field and nested field in dot notation `'field.nestedField'`. I have updated it in the above function.